# How to create JSON nested Objects using NodeJS and JSON.stringify()

Tags: node.js, json

My problem is in the port_password.

```
{
    "server": "0.0.0.0",
    "server_ipv6": "::",
    "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_port": 1080,
    "timeout": 120,
    "method": "aes-256-cfb",
    "protocol": "origin",
    "protocol_param": "",
    "obfs": "tls1.2_ticket_auth",
    "obfs_param": "",
    "redirect": "",
    "dns_ipv6": false,
    "fast_open": true,
    "workers": 1,
    "port_password": "{\"10000\":\"pass\",\"10001\":\"pass\",\"10002\":\"pass\",}"
}
```

The code I used to generate JSON.

```
account.forEach(ssr => {

     portsPasswords += JSON.stringify(ssr.port.toString()) + ':' + JSON.stringify(ssr.password.toString()) + ','

})
```

I want the output something like this. How can I achieve that using NodeJS and JSON.stringfy()?

```
{
    "server": "0.0.0.0",
    "server_ipv6": "::",
    "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_port": 1080,
    "timeout": 120,
    "method": "aes-256-cfb",
    "protocol": "origin",
    "protocol_param": "",
    "obfs": "tls1.2_ticket_auth",
    "obfs_param": "",
    "redirect": "",
    "dns_ipv6": false,
    "fast_open": true,
    "workers": 1,
    "port_password": {
       "10000":"pass",
       "10001":"pass",
       "10002":"pass"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` into an object instead:

```js
const account = [
  { port: 10000, password: 'pass1' },
  { port: 10001, password: 'pass2' },
  { port: 10002, password: 'pass3' }
];
const port_password = account.reduce((a, { port, password }) => {
  a[port] = password;
  return a;
}, {});

const entireObj = {
  "server": "0.0.0.0",
  // etc
  port_password
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(entireObj));
```

Comment: As a newbie, I really appreciate your help bro! You save my day! This is my first time to get answer from stack overflow. Thank you so much! Even I don't get how function reduce() works. It worked now. :)